# Join data from 4 topics in broker using Kafka Streams when updates are not same in each of the topics

Tags: left-join, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am working on a requirement to process data ingested from a SQL Data store to Kafka Broker in 4 different topics corresponding to 4 different tables in the SQL Data Store. I am using Kafka Connect to ingest the data into the topics.

I now want to join the data from these topics and aggregate them and write them back to another topic. This topic will in turn be subscribed by a consumer to populate a NOSQL Data store which will be used to render the UI.

I know Kafka Streams can be used to join topics.

My query is, the data being ingested from SQL Data store tables may not always have data for all the 4 tables. Only 2 of the tables will have regular updates. One will get updated but not in the same frequency as the other 2. The remaining one is a static (sort of master table).

So, I am not sure how we can actually join them with Kafka Streams when the record counts will  mismatch in topics.

Has anyone faced a similar issue . If so, can you please provide your thoughts/code snippets on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of rows don't matter at all... Why should it have any impact on the join result?

You can just read all 4 topics as a `KTable` each, and do the join. Finally, you apply an aggregation to the join-result `KTable` and write the final result to a topic. Something like this:

```java
KTable t1 = builder.table("topic1");
KTable t2 = builder.table("topic2");
KTable t3 = builder.table("topic3");
KTable t4 = builder.table("topic4");

KTable joinResult = t1.join(t2, ...).join(t3, ...).join(t4, ...);

joinResult.groupByKey(...).aggregate(...).to("result-topic);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Below is our scenario.  
 Table A gets updated less frequently  
 Table B get updated very offen
 Table C is master data

If we try to join Tables using KTable, there is a posibility that Table B's related data may not be available in Table A (due to topic expiration time), How to handle in this situation?

Comment: There are multiple thing to add there: (1) if you read a topic as a table, it's recommended to configure it as a compacted topic (otherwise, you might loose your latest state if case of failure). (2) if you want to use a topic with retention time setting, you should actually set retention time to infinite.

Comment: (3) another way would be, to keep the retention time as is, but don't read the topic as a table, but as a stream and convert it into a table with a dummy aggregation (http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#how-can-i-convert-a-kstream-to-a-ktable-without-an-aggregation-step). This has the advantage, that Streams creates an additional compacted changelog topic in the background and thus it prevents data loss.

Comment: Thanks. I have now got a clear idea on how to proceed with the solution.